# Framework7 Tabs

Tags: vue.js, html-framework-7

```
<f7-toolbar tabbar>
  <f7-link icon-f7="compass_fill" tab-link="#tab-1"></f7-link>
  <f7-link icon-f7="drawers_fill" tab-link="#tab-2" tab-link-active></f7-link>
  <f7-link icon-f7="pie_fill" tab-link="#tab-3"></f7-link>
</f7-toolbar>
<f7-tabs>
  <f7-tab id="tab-1">
    <f7-view url="/tab1/"></f7-view>
  </f7-tab>
  <f7-tab id="tab-2" tab-active>
    <f7-view url="/tab2/"></f7-view>
  </f7-tab>
  <f7-tab id="tab-3">
    <f7-view url="/tab3/"></f7-view>
  </f7-tab>
</f7-tabs>
```

I really dont know why, but my Views are not Displayed? Does anyone know why they are not displayed?

Answer (score 0):

let me give you an unprofessional advice but it works. goto to http://framework7.io/docs/tabs.html

and you will just copy and paste the tabs template then edit.

From what i can see yours are not working because i cant seem to see the class `.f7-toolbar` but its simply using the class `.toolbar`. 
From the look of your current code every class with a prefix `.f7-` is not gonna work unless if you are using a version which is not `v2`